# class not Registered HRESULT error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I've created An application that I have placed on a server. Of the 27 machines I have put a shortcut to the application on, 3 of them are getting this error. From everything that I've looked at I've gathered that it has something to do with a Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll file. This may be completely incorrect though. Would anyone be able/willing to tell me 1) what is this error/ why am I getting it? 2) why is it occuring on only a few machines? 3) a general idea of how to fix it. Please and Thanks

```
 ************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1008 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DailyEntrySystem
    Assembly Version: 2.0.1.1
    Win32 Version: 2.0.1.1
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/DailyEntrySystem.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1002 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1015 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1015 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1015 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.UI
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.UI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Breeze
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Breeze.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Aqua
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Aqua.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Black
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Black.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Windows7
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Windows7.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.Themes.VisualStudio2012Light
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.Themes.VisualStudio2012Light.DLL
----------------------------------------
TelerikCommon
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/TelerikCommon.DLL
----------------------------------------
metdxdny
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.237 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data
    Assembly Version: 1.0.4244.17850
    Win32 Version: 1.0.4244.17850
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.AcroPDFLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.GridView
    Assembly Version: 2013.2.724.40
    Win32 Version: 2013.2.724.40
    CodeBase: file://192.168.254.52/c$/_mfdc/DailyEntrySystem/bin/Release/Telerik.WinControls.GridView.DLL
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems most likely that you're getting that error because you're using a PDF viewer that is referencing a dll that comes with Acrobat Reader, and that program isn't installed on those 3 machines. You need to install Acrobat Reader on each PC which uses your application.